# Обращение к приватному методу извне

Tags: java, классы, методы

Есть задача, в которой нужно поэкспериментировать с объектами типа Cat.
Мы создали 5 кошек и делаем с ними разные вещи.
С одной из этих кошек, я хочу провернуть зверство и замяукать ее до смерти.
Есть метод meow, который при вызове сжигает 1 грамм веса кошки и печатает в консоль meow.

Как написать правильный цикл, который повторял бы мяуканье кошки, пока ее вес больше 0 ?

```
while (murka.weigth > 0){
      murka.meow();
}
```

Но у меня не получается, среда разработки пишет "weight has private acess to cat"
Насколько я понял, класс этой кошки публичный,а вот параметры в нм приватные чем сулит изменение этих переменных на на публичные ?
Есть ли способ, не меняя уровень приватности получать значения weith ?

```
public class Cat
{
private Double originWeight;
private Double weight;

private Double minWeight;
private Double maxWeight;

public Cat()
{
    weight = 1500.0 + 3000.0 * Math.random();
    originWeight = weight;
    minWeight = 1000.0;
    maxWeight = 9000.0;
}
```

Comment: небольшой оффтоп, используйте примитивы вместо Double

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Насколько я понял, класс этой кошки публичный,а вот параметры в нём
>   приватные чем сулит изменение этих переменных на на публичные ?

Сулит тем что нарушается принцип инкапсуляции.

> Есть ли способ, не меняя уровень приватности получать значения weith ?

Есть, используйте такой метод:

```
public Double getWeight() {
    return weight;
}
```

Comment: Т.е. если я правильно понял смысл такого выражения примерно такой:
Пока, взять вес мурки, и если он больше нуля, мяукнуть. Повторить.

Другими словами я спрашиваю сколько у коши осталось веса, после чего провожу цикл.
А до этого пытался взять само значение из "закрытого" источника"

Прошу прощение за вольное изложение, мне так проще понять принцип того что я делаю

Comment: Да, принцип инкапсуляции придуман для того чтобы тот кто работал с кошкой, не мог поменять ей вес. Мы можем ее взвесить (вызвать метод getWeight), но не можем взять и отрезать кусок кошки или пришить часть, чтобы получить меньший или больший вес. Изменить вес кошки могут лишь действия самой кошки- мяуканье, поглощение еды, прогулка и т.д.

Comment: Так же можно заменить `murka.weigth > 0` на `!murka.isEmpty()` и сравнивать вес с нулем уже внутри Cat().